# Tornar referência global no C#

Tags: c#, windows

Estou criando um sistema simples de operações sem banco de dados no C#. Possui 3 Forms, sendo eles: **Login.cs**, **Cadastro.cs** e **Main.cs**. Também possui a classe **Conta.cs**, onde é realizada as operações.

Minha dúvida é o seguinte: no **form Cadastro.cs** eu criei uma referência chamada **mconta** e eu gostaria que ela fosse global. Nessa caso somente o próprio **Cadastro.cs** tem acesso a ela.

```
Conta[] mconta;
mconta = new Conta[10];
```

Comment: Quase sempre isso é errado.

Answer (score 2):

Há várias formas de fazer isso, inclusive há um padrão chamado `Singleton` que poderia atender dependendo do seu caso, vou colocar apenas uma forma, simples, mas acho fica "bagunçado" aí teria que ver como está seu código, sua organização, enfim...

Na própria classe Conta, defina uma variável como `public static`:

```
public class Conta
{
    //Declare sua variável:
    public static Conta[] mConta = new Conta[10];
}
```

Em qualquer outra classe, você consegue acessá-la apenas pelo nome da classe:

```
... Conta.mConta;
```

Mas, recomendo que reveja sua necessidade, não me parece necessário isso. Outra questão é utilizar coleções genéricas ao invés de array, é muito mais simples e prático:

```
List<Conta> mConta = new List<Conta>();
```

Comment: No primeiro código não deveria criar como `public static class Conta` ?

Comment: Depende da necessidade... Se é uma classe estática, ou uma variável estática, no meu exemplo utilizo uma variável, ou seja, uma instância da classe